# Gas line addition to external building - can I avoid expanding all existing lines?

Tags: gas, boiler, natural-gas

I'm adding an external building with hydronic heating and a variable boiler (160k BTU max) which will be about a 100' feet from the existing gas meter.

I had planned to simply tap into the existing gas line (which was oversized originally), but when calculating the additional length/gas needs, it appears that I will need to re-plumb some of the existing lines to accommodate this new longest branch run. Yikes ... not cool. I really don't want to pull apart walls to change existing gas lines.

Can anyone suggest options? I suppose one of them could include a new, separate gas meter for this distinct building or ?

[image]

*N.B. Running a T from the meter and routing around the building isn't a possibility due to a number of constraints, including concrete hardscape.*

Comment: This really can’t be answered without a plot plan.  As written it sounds like the current supply goes into one end of the existing building and you want to exit the other end to extend the line, if that’s the case go around the existing building instead of thought it?  Consider editing a diagram into your question.

Comment: With the plot plan added I would probably T at the gas meter and run the new line under ground outside. For new runs like this I prefer poly gas line, less couplings and easier to put in the trench.